# Opening a XIB from a storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, storyboard, xib

After a few other problems I have implemented a storyboard into my app to solve them. 
However I now need some help in opening an existing Xib which is not part of the storyboard when you click a button on a storyboard view

Can someone please give me some code examples that you might use on a button to open a xib.

I have tried to use an IBAction but that appears to not be working.

An even better idea is to get the XIB in the storyboard but I dont know if you can do that

thanks :)

EDIT :-

```
- (IBAction)changeratings:(id)sender
{
RSSTableViewController *rss2 = [[RSSTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RSSTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:rss2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: have you connected your outlet in xib of storyboard

Comment: i have yes. I made sure i had a clean outlet as well. removed the old Xib i was using as a first screen and placed in the storyboard. Disconnected the outlets from the old xib and reconnected to the new storyboard view.

Comment: what is your code you have written in for opening that new xib?

Comment: - (IBAction)changeratings:(id)sender {
    RSSTableViewController *rss2 = [[RSSTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RSSTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:rss2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}

Comment: RSSTableViewController is the xib :)

Comment: try addSubView instead of presentViewController..

Comment: can you possibly show me how that fits into my code? so self addSubView:rss2?

Comment: [self.view addSubView: rss2.view];

Comment: crashes with unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x752a040

Comment: crash is in main.m on this line @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));